# value != float or value != int does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, floating-point-conversion

i'm trying to make a calculator that can do 5 processes which are to add, subtract, multiply, divide and square root values that users input. all of that i've done, but when trying to make the values != float and int, the error comes for when the input values are float and int... i've tried value == str then error to come up, but even that doesnt work... anyone help me please?

e.g.

```
if value[0] != 'float' or value[0] != 'int' or value[1] != 'float' or value[1] != int':
    return 'the input value is not correct
```

i've tried both the two in the above and it does not seem to work. as in the program is not able to read between a float, int and a string.

if i input

```
calculator('+', 3, 4)
```

the result says the error.....

the reason why i have the 'print type(value[0], [1]) is to make sure the types they are for the error that keeps on occuring. 
`

```
def calculator(sym, *t):
    value = tuple(t)
    n = len(value)

    print type(value[0])
    print type(value[1])

    if value[0] != 'float' or value[0] != 'int' or value[1] != 'float' or value[1] != int':
        return 'the input value is not correct.'
    else:
        if sym == '+':
            if len(value) != 2:
                return 'The input value is not correct.'
            else:
                return float(value[0] + value[1])
        elif sym == '-':
            if len(value) != 2:
                return 'The input value is not correct.'
            else:
                return float(value[0] - value[1])
        elif sym == '/':
            if len(value) != 2:
                return 'The input value is not correct.'
            elif value[1] == 0:
                return 'The input value is not correct.'
            else:
                return float(value[0] / value[1])
        elif sym == '*':
            if len(value) != 2:
                return 'The input value is not correct.'
            else:
                return float(value[0] * value[1])
        elif sym == 'sqrt':
            if len(value) != 1:
                return 'The input value is not correct.'
            elif value[0] < 0:
                return 'The input value is not correct.'
            else:
                return value[0] ** 0.5
        else:
            return 'The input value is not correct.'
```

`

Comment: You're printing `type(value[0])`, but you compare against `value[0]`...

Comment: It doesn't matter much here, but please always copy and paste your code exactly.  That can't be running code because of the syntax error in `or value[1] != int'`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check type:

```
>>> isinstance(1, int)
True
>>> isinstance(1, float)
False
>>> isinstance('str', int)
False
```

You can use [`numbers.Number`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number) to match any kind of number object:

```
>>> import numbers
>>> isinstance(2, numbers.Number)
True
>>> isinstance(2.0, numbers.Number)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare the values against *strings*, not types. Use the [`isinstance()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to test for types instead, it accepts a tuple of types:

```
if not (isinstance(value[0], (int, float)) and isinstance(value[1], (int, float))):
```

Note that `float` and `int` are names here, not string literals. They refer to the built-in type objects.